# xscreensaver build - failing on make install

Tags: software-installation, make, xscreensaver

For a couple years now I've been building locally xscreensaver using the

```
 .configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

combination.

Today however the `sudo make install` is failing with permission issues:

```
 sudo make install
 [sudo] password for stephen: 
 make: stat: GNUmakefile: Permission denied
 make: stat: makefile: Permission denied
 make: stat: Makefile: Permission denied
 make: stat: install: Permission denied
 make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

I tried without sudo and there was no difference.

Comment: Sounds odd, what file system are you using?

Comment: @andrew.46 ext4 This is a fresh install of 20.10 , installed yesterday.

Comment: I've seen errors like this before when one of the files didn't have the executable bit set.

Comment: @KGIII   That was it. `Makefile` was not executable.

Comment: Yup. That's what I figured it was. I could write it up as an answer, but it'd be relatively short.

Comment: @KGIII Short answers are the best. When they do the job as yours does. You could make it long by explaining what files must be executable but you don't have to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this case is that the appropriate files don't have the executable bit. If the file needs to be executed, that is run as a program, then it needs to have that bit set.

In this case, to make the application you need 'makefile' to be executable. This is done with:

```
chmod +x ./<file_name>
```

Adjust your /path/to/file as needed and then, run your make command again.

```
sudo make install
```

'chmod' means to change file mode bits and the +x means executable.

Comment: Why does Makefile have to be executable? Isn't it just a file with instructions for make and not directly executed by itself?

Comment: @palapapa Because the make command may want to put files in protected directories, such as `/usr/bin` for example. If it needs no elevated permissions, you can run it as your regular user.

Comment: Doesn't setting the executable bit on Makefile just make it so that you can run `./Makefile`? But that's not what we want, is it? Isn't `sudo make` what does the trick here?

Comment: Yes, the +x sets the executable bit. You set that and then run make. That's (sometimes) followed by make install, which may need elevated permissions as it installs the made file(s) into the various system folders. You do not need sudo with just plain make.

Comment: I don't understand. `Makefile` is not a program, so why does it need to be executable? Doesn't it only need to be readable by `make`? I also can't find any information on `Makefile` itself needing to be executable. Your previous comments only address `make` but not `Makefile`.